# Can I automatically follow a header file in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

If I come across something like `#include "somewhere/myheader.h"` can I automatically jump to that header somehow?  (Similar to how gtags works?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call (ffap-bindings) in your ~/.emacs. That will bind C-x C-f to find-file-at-point.

Then place the cursor on the include line (inside the file-path) and press C-x C-f

Comment: ffap is great. Just beware that it goes in the way of ido-mode, when ido tries to rebind stuff, it will rebind 'find-file only, and not 'find-file-at-point. As a consequence <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> would only be stick with 'find-file-at-point. Ido being quite popular, one solution could be to disable ffap bindings and activate a similar feature for ido with (setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess) .

Answer (score 2):

With [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) (a standalone package for now; will be a part of Emacs 23.2) you get the command `semantic-decoration-include-visit` which does what you want.